# Opening installed PWA with a URL in browser not working

Tags: progressive-web-apps, qr-code

I'm trying to get my installed PWA to open when a QR code opens a URL in a browser. Have I got this set up correctly, or am I misunderstanding something, please?

For testing my PWA was installed from Chrome, and I'm testing putting the above URL in a Chrome browser on an Android phone.

The URL I'm putting in my browser is...

https://test.mysupersite.com?book=GGGGG

...where 'book' could be any 5 character alpha-numeral

I have a file named web-app-origin-association which is in a folder named .well-known in the root of my website i.e https://test/mysupersite.com/.well-known. It contains:

```
{
    "web_apps": [
        {
            "manifest": "https://test.mysupersite.com/manifest.webmanifest",
            "details": {
                "paths": ["/*"]
            }
        }      
    ]
}
```

My web manifest is named manifest.webmanifest and is also in my site's root...

```
https://test.mysupersite.com/manifest.webmanifest
```

It contains...

```
{
  "name": "MySuperSite",
  "short_name": "MySuperSite",
  "gcm_sender_id": "XX47XX2560XX",
  "display": "standalone",
  "gcm_user_visible_only": true,
  "start_url": "/?mode=standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "related_applications": [{
    "platform": "webapp",
    "url": "https://test.mysupersite.com/manifest.webmanifest"
 }],
  "url_handlers": [
    {
      "origin": "https://test.mysupersite.com"
    },{
      "origin": "https://*.mysupersite.com" 
    }
  ],
  "background_color": "black",
  "description": "Do super things",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/imgs/PWA-icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "/imgs/PWA-icon-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
 ]
 
}
```

If my PWA installs fine (which it does), should putting https://test.mysupersite.com?book=GGGGG in a Chrome browser on an Android phone open the installed PWA?

I've also tried putting https://test.mysupersite.com (no query string) in the browser, but it also doesn't work.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you enabled the [`#enable-desktop-pwas-url-handling`](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/pwa-url-handler/#enabling-via-aboutflags) flag
2. **This API only works with links opened outside of the browser, like in messaging apps.** It won't work when you enter the URL into the browser. Quoting the docs,

> Navigations that start in a browser tab are not handled by this proposal

Comment: Thank you @grimsteel. Ahh - so then opening a PWA with a QR code won't work because the QR code opens the url in a browser, right?

Comment: @Shaun I'm not sure. But when you install a PWA, Chrome does show an option (on desktop at least) to "Remember my choice" when opening links. I'm pretty sure if the user enables that, scanning a QR code will open it in the PWA